# Number of data points on an infographic

Tags: information-graphics, marketing

Is there an "ideal" number of data points on an infographic to maximise the impact and readability of the graphic?

I see some where there is too much text / text is so small or there are just so many data points that they all get lost amongst each other which is something I want to avoid so at what point does an infographic get too overcrowded to be effective?

Answer (score 1):

There is an ideal number. What that is is entirely dependent on all the specifics of the project. Read [Tufte's books](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/) to get a good primer on what makes for good and bad information graphics.